# XSLT getting grandchild node attribute values in template

Tags: xslt

Given XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Products>
  <Product someId="1EFAD9659EC">
    <Identifiers>
      <Identifier Id="234532423" Name="globalTradeItemNumber (GTIN)" Value="00671657621322" />
      <Identifier Id="99845898" Name="Internal Supplier Part #" Value="DEL 20 10B015000" />
      <Identifier Id="49348598" Name="MFG Model # (Series)" Value="DEL 20 10B015000" />
      <Identifier Id="439854985" Name="MFG Part # (OEM)" Value="DEL 20 10B015000" />
      <Identifier Id="2349832489" Name="UPC" Value="671657621322" />
    </Identifiers>
  </Product>    
  <Product someId="1EFAD9659EC">
    <Identifiers>
      <Identifier Id="234532423" Name="globalTradeItemNumber (GTIN)" Value="51651518" />
      <Identifier Id="99845898" Name="Internal Supplier Part #" Value="TIM 20 10B015000" />
      <Identifier Id="49348598" Name="MFG Model # (Series)" Value="TOM 20 10B015000" />
      <Identifier Id="439854985" Name="MFG Part # (OEM)" Value="TAK 20 10B015000" />
      <Identifier Id="2349832489" Name="UPC" Value="87468387468" />
    </Identifiers>
  </Product>    
      . . .
```

I want to end up with something like

```
...
  <Product upc="671657621322"/>
  <Product upc="87468387468"/>
...
```

But what I'm getting is

```
...
  <Product upc="true"/>
  <Product upc="true"/>
...
```

I keep getting the boolean answer to my select rather than the value of the attribute.  What silly thing am I doing wrong here?  This is the XSLT I'm trying:

```
...
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Output>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </Output>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Product">
        <xsl:variable name="productCode" select="./Identifiers/Identifier/@Name='UPC'"/>
        <Product upc="{$productCode}">
        </Product>
    </xsl:template>
...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong xpath selection. Use:

```
select="Identifiers/Identifier[@Name='UPC']/@Value"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested only with those two node values match them with the template:

```
<xsl:template match="Product/Identifiers/Identifier[@Name='UPC']">
    <xsl:variable name="productCode" select="@Value"/>
    <Product upc="{$productCode}">
    </Product>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Nice.  In this case I will actually need a lot of the other stuff, but I'll file that away for future use. Thanks!